# Intellij run option disappears

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a test class in Intellij. For running it, there are two options, as it can be seen in the image below:

[image]

However, this only happens the first time I select `Run`. After that, the menu doesn't show up any more. So, if I select the wrong option, I don't know how to change my selection.

How can I change the way in which the file is run?

In other words, if there are two options for running my test class `A` and `B` and if I mistakenly select `A`, I don't know how to switch to `B` again.

I'm using OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking Alt-Shitft-F10 or in the navigation bar clicking Run -> Run... should give you a list of options. Alternatively from the same Run bar you can click Edit Configurations to create your own set up.

Comment: On the OSX version of Intellij, none of those options work unfortunately.

Comment: @octavian You might be able to see some options for running near the right side (or middle) of the screen, right near the navigation bar. You should be able to see VCS buttons (if enabled), debug button and the green run button with a dropdown next to it. Anything like that on yours?

Comment: Yes, I have that `Run` menu but neither `Run ...` nor `Edit Configurations` offer me the ability to switch between ways of running my test class.

Comment: Actually, in `Edit Configurations` I am able to switch between ways of running the test class. However,  if I select another option and then click `Apply` and then try to run, the file is still ran in the same way.

Comment: You could look at your key bindings and see the short-cut for running between different configurations. Or your different configurations might actually be the same, did you look what the configurations actually are?